# Extract domain with grok

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

I'd like to make the simplest grok filter, just to extract domain from url
For example, for the url

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=grok%20extract%20url
```

I'd like to get the result

```
stackoverflow.com
```

I tried to do so with the filter

```
%{URIPROTO}://%{URIHOST:domain}
```

And it did extract me stackoverflow.com, but when I use a different url that has www at the start
for example 
https://www.elastic.co/
the result is

```
www.elastic.co
```

is there a filter that could return me the domain alone, without www?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom pattern like below :

```
SLD ([a-z0-9-]+.[a-z]{2,63})
```

This gives you second level domain name without subdomain. You can also add `xn--` pattern like below for unicode domain names:

```
SLD ((xn--)?[a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z]{2,63})
```

Please check how you can add custom pattern to [logstash documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html#_custom_patterns). Then, now, you can use this custom pattern like below:

```
%{URIPROTO}://(%{WORD:SUBDOMAIN}\.)?(%{SLD})
```

For `%{WORD:SUBDOMAIN}` this part, you can also write another regex to your custom pattern like below:

```
SUBDOMAIN ([a-z0-9-]{1,63})
```

At the end, your pattern file like this :

```
SLD ((xn--)?[a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z]{2,63})
SUBDOMAIN ([a-z0-9-]{1,63})
```

And your logstash conf like this:

```
filter {
  grok {
    patterns_dir => ["./patterns"]
    match => { "uri" => "%{URIPROTO}://(%{SUBDOMAIN}\.)?(%{SLD})" }
  }
}
```

Comment: SLD won't work on the sites like, google.co.uk - it will return co.uk only... Correct way will be to use public suffix list to find "registrable" domains.

Comment: Hmm, thats right, Should I list all registrable domains in my regex or do you have any other solution for this? @AlexOtt

Comment: PSL is quite big list, and have special rules for handling. The correct way would be to add extension to logstash that would able to extract registrable domain using the java library...

Comment: but for dropping www, it would be enough to use regex with `gsub`

Answer (score 0):

Please define grok pattern:

```
HOSTNAME \b(?:[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z-]{0,62})(?:\.(?:[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z-]{0,62}))*(\.?|\b)
```

and use it:

```
%{URIPROTO}://%{HOSTNAME:domain}
```